# Problems dockerizing Laravel application - database hosts array is empty

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to dockerize existing Laravel + Vue.js application, however, when trying to access database getting an error:

> Database hosts array is empty.

It looks like that connection fails from PHP to MYSQL (but MySQL image is running and I can connect to it from terminal). Not sure how to proceed with this. It doesn't look to me a misconfiguration. Is there a way to debug it?

Here is what I have:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  backoffice:

services:
  backoffice_nginx:
    image: nginx:stable
    container_name: backoffice_nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8088:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - backoffice_php
    networks:
      - backoffice

  backoffice_mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.13
    container_name: backoffice_mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "33067:3306"
    command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci', '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password']
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_db
      MYSQL_USER: dbuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypass
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: myrootpass
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/db:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d
    networks:
      - backoffice

  backoffice_php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: backoffice_php
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - backoffice

  backoffice_composer:
    image: composer:latest
    container_name: backoffice_composer
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - backoffice_php
    networks:
      - backoffice


  backoffice_artisan:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: backoffice_artisan
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['php', '/var/www/html/artisan']
    networks:
      - backoffice
```

`php.dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath pdo pdo_mysql

RUN pecl install -o -f redis \
&&  rm -rf /tmp/pear \
&&  docker-php-ext-enable redis
```

DB configs part in the `.env`:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=backoffice_mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=my_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=myrootpass
```

Here are running containers:
[image: docker containers]

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: This error is normally produced when db host value is null. *Could* be that in your database config file, the env constant referenced is not `DB_DATABASE`, so might be worth checking db config file just to be sure. (Also, shouldn't your port be 33067? just thinking aloud; my docker knowledge is not good)

Comment: @user3532758, thanks for reminding me that, it was a configuration issue and tweaking configurations solved my issue (it is progect specific so I am not adding that here). Regarding the port number it should be internal port number as the connection goes inside the "docker compose".

Answer (score 1):

You are not sharing your .env file with your container. Map your whole . Volume to the container instead of only your ./src directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually `.env` is inside the `./src` directory, outside are only docker/docker related files.